# Is there any way to use a Wordpress function within an AJAX output and pass through the returned object as a parameter?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In a nutshell, I'm using AJAX to retrieve a bunch of custom posts, which I am then displaying how I want.

The problem I'm facing is within my output, I now need to use some WordPress functions, in particular 'get_the_post_thumbnail_url()'. But I need to be able to pass through the returned object ID value as the first parameter.

I've tried every combination of quote, escaping etc nothing has seemed to be able to combine the PHP Function with the AJAX object value, so I'm wondering if this is actually possible or not.

Code wise, the AJAX call is working fine (I can retrieve everything contained within get_posts() such as the title, content, ID etc. I just can't see how I can take any of these values and pass them into a PHP Function to use.

IS this possible?

```
function kwt21_three_card_reading_js() {
    
    return 'jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "'.admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                action : "kwt21_three_card_reading_get_cards"
            },
            success: function(response) {
            
                jQuery("#kwt21-three-card-reading").html("<div class=\"row\"></div>");
                
                jQuery.each( response, function( key, value ) {
                
                    if(key === 0) {
                        var cardID      = "the-past";
                        var cardTitle   = "The Past";
                    }
                    if(key === 1) {
                        var cardID      = "the-present";
                        var cardTitle   = "The Present";
                    }
                    if(key === 2) {
                        var cardID      = "the-future";
                        var cardTitle   = "The Future";
                    }
                    
                    var count = 0;
                    
                    jQuery("#kwt21-three-card-reading > .row").append(
                    
                        // Card
                        "<div class=\"col-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0\">" +
                            "<div class=\"card  border-0 bg-transparent\">" +
                                "<div class=\"card-body p-0 text-center\">" +
                                    "<h3 class=\"card-title h5 mb-0\">" +
                                        "<a href=\"#" + cardID + "\" data-bs-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"stretched-link\">" +
                                            "<img src=\"'.wp_get_attachment_image_url(40917, 'medium').'\" />" +
                                        "</a>" +
                                    "</h3>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        
                        // Modal
                        "<div id=\"" + cardID + "\" class=\"modal three-card-reading-modal\" tabindex=\"-1\">" +
                            "<div class=\"modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered\">" +
                                "<div class=\"modal-content\">" +
                                    "<div class=\"modal-body\">" +
                                        "<div class=\"row\">" + 
                                            "<div class=\"col-md-4\">" +
                                                "<img src=\"" + '.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(<!-- I need to use value["ID"] here -->).' + "\" />" +
                                            "</div>" +
                                            "<div class=\"col-md-8\">" +
                                                "<h3 class=\"modal-title h5 mb-3 text-uppercase text-spaced\">" +
                                                    cardTitle +
                                                "</h3>" +
                                                "<h4 class=\"h5 mb-3 text-uppercase text-spaced\">" +
                                                    value["post_title"] +
                                                "</h4>" +
                                                "<div class=\"modal-text\">" +
                                                    value["post_content"] +
                                                "</div>" +
                                            "</div>" +
                                        "</div>" +
                                    "</div>" +
                                "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>"

                    );
                    
                    console.log(key, value);
                    
                });
                
            }
        });';
    
}
```

Comment: The ajax call doesn't make sense, where are you calling the ajax request, and in what way is the result related to the content you are calling it from. you want to send some data to php to parse and then return a result as JSON. For example your in a category page and you want to lazy load the next page of results you would send the category id and the page number to wordpress.

Comment: The AJAX call makes sense, what I'm asking is how I can use a wordpress PHP function within the output. I have the ID in the result I want to parse through it, but no matter how I try and enter the function with arguments, it doesn't seem to work. I can gather it's to do with syntax and formatting, but I just am looking for some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the likes of this would be what your looking at.

```
//Allow calling for Logged in users
add_action("wp_ajax_kwt21_three_card_reading_get_cards","kwt21_three_card_reading_get_cards");
//Allow calling for Non Logged in users
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_kwt21_three_card_reading_get_cards","kwt21_three_card_reading_get_cards");

function kwt21_three_card_reading_get_cards(){
/* Parse the received data here and return it as a JSON object*/

  return json_encode ($result);
}
```

Comment: I know how to return stuff, I need to know how to use a WP php function in the output, and pass through the ID.. as in my code. Sorry but your code doesn't help me. Can you explain how I can get the ID of the post from $result, and then use that inside a PHP function in the output?

Comment: Ok, the php function you added to your question where exactly is it called ?